# AS3 Classes - Should I use them?

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash-cs4

I'm working on a project in Flash CS4/AS3 and I have a document class set up but I am wondering about using that, as opposed to frame-based scripting. Most of what I have seen so far deals with how to create them, but doesn't offer much about why or when to use them.

I know I can also pull in other classes beyond the document class but, again, why and when?

Could I get some input from you fine people out there on usage/best practice, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If this is just a simple demo or a movie, you can use the time line.

But if you're going to make a program, with classes, you should have a document class.
A document class is the main class of your programs. it's actually your initializer of all the program's processes and components, and it's simply more proper and similar to other programming languages.

Plus, it's in a different file, and it is easier to edit it this way. 
Also, your doc-class will be a class and not just code in the air.. it also has auto-complete in CS5.